# MATLAB GUI: I want to display an error message if user selects the wrong file type

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have an option for users to open wav files (using `uigetfile`). However, this doesn't stop them opening all file types and when they do this it breaks my GUI.

How can I get an error message to occur when they don't open a wav file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you get the file name with `uigetfile`,  check if its last four characters are ".wav". The comparison can be done with `strncmp`. (Note that the file name could have less than four characters, so you can't do something like `all(filename(end-3:end)=='.wav')`).

```
[filename, pathname, filterindex] = uigetfile('*.wav',' Select file');
if ~strncmp(fliplr(filename),'vaw.',4)
    error('Invalid file type')
end
```

---

If, instead of throwing an error, you want the file dialog to reappear when the file type is not correct:

```
done = 0;
while ~done
    [filename, pathname, filterindex] = uigetfile('*.wav',' Select file');
    done = filterindex==0 || strncmp(fliplr(filename),'vaw.',4);
end
```

The `filterindex==0` check is needed to avoid an infinite loop when the user presses "Cancel". As per the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html), that output parameter is zero in that case.